# Else part is executed even when the if condition is true in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, for-loop, if-statement

strong textI want to get the user input and search for it through the array of objects .
I use for in to ***iterate through the array of object*** and if loop for comparing .If the if condition is true the current object  details needs to be displayed to the user and if not found show an error message.My code works fine if only the If condition is provided but if the else condition is provided only the else block is executed always.
**My html :**

```
 <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name"><br>
 <input type="button" value="Get Pokemon Details" id="pokedetails">
```

JS:

```
for (var n in data.pokemon) {
if (data.pokemon[n].name.toLowerCase() === value.toLowerCase()) {
  let a = data.pokemon[n];
  displayDetails(a);
  console.log(a);
  break;
}else {
alert('invalid name');
}}}
```

My javascript code so long for the viewing purpose i have included in jsfiddle please visit there for the full script file.[Click Here to Visit JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekm3112/pcu5jfyd/)

what was the problem with my code or any solution for this?

This is my first question in Stackoverflow apologies if you find something strange while reading or understanding the question.

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: `.hasOwnProperty(next_evolution)` — where is the variable `next_evolution` defined? You mean the _string_: `.hasOwnProperty("next_evolution")`.

Comment: *"Else part is executed even when the if condition is true in Javascript"* No, it isn't. Let go of that belief so you can see what's really happening.

Comment: **Please** don't **randomly** boldface parts **of** your text. It **makes** it very hard to **read**.

Comment: @Xufox the next_evolution  is one of the object in the data provided.For that function i just want to check whether the input name is present in the next_evolution object and display the name of the pokemon

Comment: @Vivekm If `next_evolution` was really an “object”, you’d have failed to demonstrate how it was defined, and you’d have misunderstood the documentation of [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) which states that it accepts either a string or a symbol, _or_ you mean “property” instead, in which case, you’d still have failed to demonstrate how it was defined, or missed the quotes, as I was suggesting in my comment.

Comment: @Xufox thank you for mentioning..

Answer (score 0):

Using the temp variable solves the issue.

```js
  var flag=0;
  for (var n in data.pokemon) {
    if (data.pokemon[n].name.toLowerCase() === value.toLowerCase()) {      
      flag=1;
      break;      
    }
  }
  if (flag==1){
    let a = data.pokemon[n];
      displayDetails(a);
      console.log(a);
  }
  else{
    alert('Invalid Name');
  }
}
```